# How do get id of calling element for JavaScript onclick

Tags: javascript, c#, getelementbyid

I have a GridView where each row has information and when the user clicks on the row more, related, information is displayed in a separate DIV (this works) but when I want to access row (to change/add css classes on click) I cannot target the row.  How do I target the row that the JavaScript onclick event is assigned to?

Here is a very stripped down version of the code:

```
protected void vd_gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "showTest(this)");
    }
}
```

Here is the JS that is called onclick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showTest(test) {
        // var rowTest1 = document.getElementById(this);
        // var rowTest2 = document.getElementById(this.id);
        // var rowTest3 = document.getElementById(test);
        // var rowTest4 = document.getElementById(test.id);

        var row = document.getElementById(test.id);
        var currentClass = row .className;

        row.className += "testClass";
    }
</script>
```

When debugging the page this is the error generated:

```
Empty string passed to getElementById().
```

Comment: Debug tip: add a `console.log(test);` line to the function, now look in the browser console to see exactly what has been passed in and what properties are available to use.

Comment: This results in the entire contents of the 'row' with all of its properties being listed but id is empty.  I guess I need to set the id manually where the JS event gets assigned to the row?

Comment: Why not do `test.className` since it is already the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this is what I did:

```
row.Attributes["id"] = gv.ID + "_row_" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
```

And get the reference here:

```
var row = document.getElementById(test.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try test.target.id 
Because I think you calling an event when the button click. So this will pass the event in that test.

Comment: This results in: "test.target is undefined"